# Mailchimp API 3.0 equivalent of older export API campaignSubscriberActivity

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm looking for the equivalent of the older [`campaignSubscriberActivity` export options](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/export/1.0/campaignsubscriberactivity.func.php). Specifically, I need to get all activity for campaign since a certain date. Is that possible in 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

As I see in the 3.0 API References You cant filter the date. So you have to filter the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
GET /reports/{campaign_id}/email-activity
```

https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/reports/email-activity/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `since` parameter on your requests to API 3.0.

Like Sergey Shushert said, you can use the reports endpoint to get open, click, and other activity for a campaign. The `since` parameter lets you filter by date. For instance, https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/open-reports/list-campaign-open-details/